# Create a field from set of 2 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can we always create a field from a set of at least $2$ elements?
For addition I considered a function: $A\times A \rightarrow A$.
If $a+b=b+a=a+a \rightarrow a $.
If $b+b \rightarrow b$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly you can make a field from two elements. Every field of a prime number, $p$, of elements is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Here $p=2$.

If $a+a = a$ and $b+b=b$ then $a=0$ and $b=0$ by the additive inverse. So your operations would not be valid for a field where $a\neq b$. Another way to see it is $b+a = a+a \implies b=a$.

This is how the operations would have to work out:

$$a + b = b + a = a$$
$$a + a = b = b+b$$
$$a \cdot a = a$$
$$a \cdot b = b = b\cdot b$$

etc. Basically $a=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $b=0$.

Comment: What's happening in case, when set has non-prime number of element>?

Answer (score 1):

The cardinal of a finite field must be the power of a prime. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness).